# SQL RegEx Group

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I'm having issues getting `regexp_extract` to work with Hive. The issues seems to be around the grouping. I'm basically extracting information from a URL between the `/` characters, I want to select not the first match, but say the Nth match.

The URL may look like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/dghahjsg/ahfgajhfg/shjagdhjasg/text/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings
```

and I want to extract the `text` part.

For example I am trying:

```
regexp_extract(cs.context_page_url, '(\/.?\/)', 5)
```

Comment: I guess `regexp_extract(URL,'^(?:[^/]*/){7}([^/]*)', 1)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use split(), which is also regex-based.

Demo

```
select split(str, '/+')[6] 
from
(select 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/dghahjsg/ahfgajhfg/shjagdhjasg/text/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings' str
)s
```

returns:

```
_c0
----
text
```

Also `/` is not a special character in regex and needs no escaping

`/+` means one or more `/`.

If you remove `+` then the position of `text` will be 7 th because of two slashes after `https:` and array index starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL,'^(?:[^/]*/){7}([^/]*)', 1)
```

[Regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/VMSrna/1).

Description:

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
Non-capturing group (?:[^/]*/){7}
  - {7} matches the previous token exactly 7 times
   Match a single character not present in the list below [^/]
   * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   / matches the character / 
/ matches the character /
1st Capturing Group ([^/]*)
  Match a single character not present in the list below [^/]
  * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  / matches the character /
```